# Is it true that $\mathbb{C}(x) \equiv \mathbb{C}(x, y)$?

Tags: field-theory, model-theory

It is easily seen that any two consecutive entries in the tower of fields given below are not elementarily equivalent in the language of rings:
$$\mathbb{Q} \subseteq \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}) \subseteq \mathbb{R} \subseteq \mathbb{C} \subseteq \mathbb{C}(t).$$
For example, $\mathbb{C} \not\equiv \mathbb{C}(t)$ since (for example) the sentence $$\forall x \ \exists y \ x = y^2$$ holds in $\mathbb{C}$ but not in $\mathbb{C}(t)$. So it seems natural to ask: are $\mathbb{C}(t)$ and $\mathbb{C}(t_1,t_2)$ elementarily equivalent? More generally, for what fields $\mathbb{F}$ is it true that $\mathbb{F}(t) \equiv \mathbb{F}(t_1,t_2)$?

There are many well-known results involving the elementary equivalence of fields of rational functions. For example, it is known that given a field $K$ which admits a unique ordering, $K(x) \equiv \mathbb{Q}(x)$ implies $K \cong \mathbb{Q}$.

I have considered trying to use the Keisler-Shelah isomorphism theorem to prove or disprove that $\mathbb{C}(t) \equiv \mathbb{C}(t_1,t_2)$, but it is not obvious as to whether or not ultrapowers corresponding to $\mathbb{C}(t)$ and $\mathbb{C}(t_1,t_2)$ are isomorphic.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Theorem 2.40 in the book *Model Theoretic Algebra* by Jensen and Lenzing gives a negative answer. This book is a great reference for questions like this, you'll probably find it very interesting. For those without access to the book, I'll summarize the reason that $\mathbb{C}(x) \not\equiv \mathbb{C}(x,y)$.

A field $K$ is called a $C_i$-field if every homogeneous polynomial of over $K$ of degree $d$ in $n$ variables, such that $n>d^i$, has a nontrivial zero in $K^n\setminus \{(0,\dots,0)\}$. It's not too hard to show that a field is $C_0$ if and only if it is algebraically closed.

Now it's a fact that $K$ is $C_i$ if and only if $K(x)$ is $C_{i+1}$. Jensen and Lenzing don't prove this, instead citing Chapter XI of Ribenboim's book *L'arithmetique des corps*, which might be difficult to track down... It would be nice if someone could post a more accessible reference. You can actually find the direction "if $K$ is $C_i$ then $K(x)$ is $C_{i+1}$" as Theorem 3.3.9 in [this thing I wrote once](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1308.3897v1.pdf), but the converse is crucial here.

Now $K_1 = \mathbb{C}(x)$ is $C_1$ but not $C_0$ (it's not algebraically closed), so $K_2 = \mathbb{C}(x,y)$ is $C_2$ but not $C_1$. Hence there is some $d^2\geq n > d^1$ and some homogeneous polynomial $p(\overline{x})$ in $n$ variables of degree $d$ over $K_2$ which has no nontrivial zero over $K_2$. Fixing $n$ and $d$ and quantifying over the coefficients, the existence of such a polynomial is described by a first-order sentence which is true in $K_2$ but not in $K_1$.

This argument generalizes to show that $\mathbb{C}(x_1,\dots,x_n)\not\equiv \mathbb{C}(x_1,\dots,x_m)$ for any $n\neq m$.